# Setting values and names for options_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, checkbox, embedded-ruby

looked around but nothing that is perfect I can find.

I have an array of @agents and want to display them in a multi select form. Currently I have:

```
        <%= f.select(:agents, options_for_select(@agents), {},{multiple: true, size: 10}) %>
```

Which shows this:

[image: Agents array view]

I want to chose what to display in the select and possibly have a checkbox if possible?

Attributes are accessible via

```
<% @agents.each do |a| %>
  <%= a.id %>
  <%= a.name %>
<% end %>
```

I want it to look as follows:

[image]

Best way for me to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution:

Thoughts?

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:agents, @agents, :id, :name) do |b| %>
    <div class="row">
      <%= b.label(class: "check_box") do %>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <%= b.check_box(class: "check_box") %>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <%= b.object.name %>
        </div>       
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```